# Radio buttons are shown badly in Chrome

Tags: css, cross-browser

In the cart page of my website the radio button are shown badly in Chrome. **If firefox looks just fine.**  I need Chrome to show them as Firefox does.

I tried this (but not working):

```
input, textarea, button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    resize: none;
}
input[type="radio"]{
    -webkit-appearance: radio;
}
```

You can add a product and view the cart page [here](http://www.rosannadlr.com/producto/collar-02560om-oro-mate/).

Take a look at the capture to see what I mean.

[image]

[image]

Comment: could be something to do with `-webkit-appearance: none;` set on `input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] ` in forms.css which is overriding your `-webkit-appearance: radio;`  Turn that off and it looks like a radio again

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem with the markup supplied.

Comment: @Pete you was right. Thanks

Comment: @JPashs little tip - right click, inspect element.  Tells you all the styles applied to the element you inspect and then you can see what is overriding any styles you expect to be there

Answer (score 0):

Generally you don't want to place pseudo classes onto an input but onto the label themselves. Nonetheless, I noticed that you have a display inline here:

```css
input[type='checkbox'],
input[type='radio'] {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

try changing that to inline-block.